# NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, jndi

I am trying to learn JMS by making two small Java applications, one which sends messages to a queue and another one that consumes the messages. Also I installed the J2EE SDK server on my computer and add to it the necessary ConnectionFactory and Destination objects. For doing this I followed [this tutorial](http://programacion.net/articulo/introduccion_a_jms_java_message_service_142). The source code I used is in the mentioned tutorial.

The problem is I cannot get rid of the below `NoInitialContextException`.

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:344)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.xeridia.jmstest.sender.Sender.lookup(Sender.java:21)
    at com.xeridia.jmstest.sender.Sender.send(Sender.java:85)
    at com.xeridia.jmstest.sender.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: I was surprised when you said that you installed "J2EE SDK Server" as that has died more than a decade ago and absolutely doesn't make sense these days. Then I realized that the tutorial you read is written in 2002. Try looking for a more recent one. Oracle's Java EE 7 tutorial, for example. Or better, go get a normal Java EE / JMS book at Amazon. Pay carefully attention to the versions and dates. In ICT, anything older than 2~3 years is likely already outdated.

Comment: Yeah, you don't get an InitialContext out of the box like that, usually you need an environment (like a proper Java EE application server) to run in to give you an InitialContext.

Comment: I tried some tutorials which were more up to date but they told me to use glassfish as queues and JMS server. When I try to create a JMS resource in that server, it throws a RuntimeException, so it must have a bug or something like that because I don't find the cause of that error through the Internet.